# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405 with asp.net web api and Angular 2

Tags: asp.net, angular, http, asp.net-web-api2

i was trying to integrate my asp.net web api with angular 2.for checking login credential in a basic way. 
asp.net web api code is

```
public void postvalidUser(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            try
            {
                var login = uData.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == UserName).ToList();
                if (login != null && login.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var log in login)
                    {
                        if (log.UserName == UserName && log.Password == Password)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("login ok");

                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                   Console.WriteLine("login fail");

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex){

                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        }
```

**login.service.ts file is as:-**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }
  postvalidUser(UserName: string, Password: string) {


    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers });

    const users = { UserName: UserName, Password: Password };
    return this._http
      .post("http://localhost:65440/api/User", users, options)
      .map(result => result.json());
  }

  }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private _loginservices: LoginService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  OnClick(UserName: string, Password:string) {
    this._loginservices.postvalidUser(UserName, Password).subscribe(users => console.log(users));

  }





}
```

now when i m running my app it showing me the error as

Failed to load "my-url": Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405 &&  OPTIONS "my-url" 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Please tell me whether my code is wrong or something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to authorize the OPTIONS requests in your backend.

The same way you authorize GET, POST and PUT requests, simply add OPTIONS to that list.

OPTIONS are, as stated, preflight requests sent by your browser to check the endpoints.

Comment: yes sir i already add OPTIONS in my web.config file with all POST PUT etc but still it is giving me same error. i also placed following code in my controller                                                                                                     // OPTIONS http-verb handler
public HttpResponseMessage OptionsUser()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    return response;
}    still i have same error

Comment: please anybody give me suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is sending off an `OPTIONS` request.

You need to either create a `HttpOptions` endpoint with the same route, or create a middle ware that intercepts all `HttpOptions` requests and returns a 200.